# what is the && means at the end of a function

Tags: c++

I am confused when reading this [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)

```
struct S
{
    virtual int f(char) const, g(int) &&; // declares two non-static member functions
    virtual int f(char), x; // compile-time error: virtual (in decl-specifier-seq)
                            // is only allowed in declarations of non-static
                            // member functions
};
```

What is the

```
virtual int g(int) &&;
```

means about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` at the end of the function mean that the function is chosen when `this` has r-value value category.

See [member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions):

> A non-static member function can be declared with no ref-qualifier, with an lvalue ref-qualifier (the token & after the parameter list) or the rvalue ref-qualifier (the token && after the parameter list). During overload resolution, non-static cv-qualified member function of class X is treated as follows:
>
> no ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X and is additionally allowed to bind rvalue implied object argument
>
> lvalue ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X
>
> rvalue ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type rvalue reference to cv-qualified X